# what should I use to read json after every few minutes in android?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

In my MainActivity, I am reading a JSON in an asynctask every 30 minutes.

How can I know from a second activity that this JSON (read in Main) is updated?

Any ideas.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: you need to implement service that retrive json data every 30 minutes. 
this tutorial will help you out : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Comment: you can send a broadcast msg when the async finish updating the file, and handle it in the received intent in the second activity.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, I solved the issue using a LocalBroadcastManager.

Answer (score 0):

After receive data yo can broadcast that data is received and your broadcast receiver in activity2 will receive that broadcast.

Or

Use Event bus for notify activity 2